# dpkg: error: reading package info file /usr/local/var/lib/dpkg/status

Tags: package-management, software-installation, dpkg

I was installing a package from source and checkinstall produced

dpkg:error: reading package info file '/usr/local/var/lib/dpkg/status': Is a directory

The "status" directory was missing i went and made the directory but dont know how to make the info file. I may have some backups but not sure which one to use. From what i've been reading I think dpkg has been corrupted sort of.

```
phantom@AsusK53E:~$ tree -d /usr/local/var/lib/dpkg
/usr/local/var/lib/dpkg
├── alternatives
├── info
├── methods
│   ├── disk
│   ├── floppy
│   ├── ftp
│   ├── mnt
│   └── multicd
├── parts
├── status
└── updates

11 directories
```

Copied the status and availalbe files from /var/lib/dpkg to 
/usr/local/var/lib/dpkg and the checkinstall completed without error.

Comment: You did something wrong, usually DPKG-cache is located in top-level - */var/lib/dpkg/status*. And deb-files created with checkinstall are saved to this database.  Please add output of `tree -d /usr/local/var/lib/dpkg` to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just creating a directory called status won't get you what you need. /var/lib/dpkg/status is supposed to be a **file**, **not a directory** as seen below:

```
ll /var/lib/dpkg/status
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3466281 May 26 06:17 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Provided all you've done wrong is delete the status file and attempt to replace it with a directory you should be able to simply issue the following commands:

`rmdir /var/lib/dpkg/status`

`sudo cp /var/lib/dpkg/status-old /var/lib/dpkg/status`

**if you've somehow managed to move the entire /var/lib/dpkg branch** and graft it to the /usr/local branch you'll need to move it back first.

the `/var/lib/dpkg` branch typically looks like this:

```
tree -d  /var/lib/dpkg
/var/lib/dpkg
├── alternatives
├── info
├── parts
├── triggers
└── updates
```

Source: shamelessly modified from [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/161869/67643) to [this question.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/161866/67643)

Comment: /var/lib/dpkg/status is present. The error from checkinstall shows the file is missing from this path usr/local/var/lib/dpkg/status

Comment: cp the status-old to /usr/local/var/lib/dpkg/status it checkinstall completed without error

Comment: @m0ng00se I'm glad my answer was helpful to you! Cheers!

Comment: @ElderGeek, How to move it back to /var/lib/dpkg if I accidentally managed it to /usr/local.  I already create new dir in /var/lib/dpkg, but it still gives me error when installing software: `update-alternatives: error: cannot append to '/usr/local/var/log/alternatives.log': No such file or directory`.

Comment: @bagustris If you have a different question feel free to [ask](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) and link to this one if you feel it provides context. There are [many answers here](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=askubuntu+how+to+move+a+file&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) on how to move a file.